# cat is not affected by encoding issues?

Tags: bash, vim, character-encoding, cat

I have all and the same problems with encoding text files that everyone has. I work with linux terminal (gnome-terminal) and with and ssh connection to a linux server, my clients have OSX and MS Windows 7 and 10, and they are server for a webservice that i didn't know, but they alway sent me text files that can't be processed by my scripts (bash scripts) because encoding problems. The solution is so simple: i make:

```
cat textfile
```

Then i select the text in the terminal and with vim just paste the output.

So, my question is:

cat is not affected by encoding? Or is vim? or is gnome-terminal the one who cares a sh$%6 about the encoding?

Comment: `cat` simply copies the bytes of the file to standard output. Interpretation is up to the device/emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're selecting the text in the terminal only the text and the regular line endings gets selected and copied. `cat` has nothing to do with it as Barmar commented.

If you're using vim you change line ending with `:set ff=unix` and save (`:wq`). 
If the encoding is messed up that can be fixed with `:set fileencoding=utf-8` or what encoding you use.

Comment: I didn't know about these options in set (ff and dileconding). Those work perfectly with messed up files. Thanks